# use input to put on function and multiple choice

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, input, web-crawler

I wanna use and multiple choice as input to put in my funcion and run it . for example I defined a function that has url input:

```
function('test.com/type1/type2')
```

and I wanna give an input of type1 and type2 . for example if sb choose type1 and type2 as xxx and yyy I put it in my function and run it as :

```
function('test.com/xxx/yyy')
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the inputs into strings

```
type1 = "xxx"
type2 = "yyy"

function('test.com/' + type1 + '/' + type2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an f-string to add your inputs to the function:

```
function(f'test.com/{type1}/{type2}')
```